# Show $\mathcal{L}$ does not contain a finite subcover.

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following open cover of $(0,1)$:

$ \mathcal{L} = \left\lbrace \left(- \frac{x}{2}, \frac{x+1}{2}\right): 0 < x < 1 \right\rbrace$

How would you show that $\mathcal{L}$ does not contain a finite subcover?

Comment: $(x+1)/2<1$ for any $x<1$.

Comment: Any finite subset of $\mathcal L$ would be $\mathcal J = \{(-\frac {x_i}2, \frac {x_i+1}2): x_i \in (0,1) \}$ for some finite set {x_0....... x_n}.  Let $y = \max$ of those xes.  Not any $m: \frac {y+1}2 < m < 1$ is not covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathcal J \subset \mathcal L$ is a finite subset, then $\mathcal J = \{(-\frac x2, \frac {x+1}2): x \in \{x_0,.... x_n\} \subset (0,1)\}$ for some finite set of $x_i$.

As $\{x_0...., x_n\}$ is finite it has a maximal element, $y$.  $ \frac {y + 1} 2 < 1$.  Let $m$ be such $ \frac {y + 1} 2 < m < 1$

If $x_k \in \{x_0...., x_n\}$ then $\frac {x_k + 1}2 \le \frac {y+1}2 < m < 1$ so $m$ is not covered by $\mathcal J$.

So no finite subset of $\mathcal L$ can be a subcover.